# Javascript Creating a Cookie within a different funtion

Tags: javascript, html, function, cookies

My problem is I am trying to call a function to create a cookie within a different function. For some reason the createCookie function does not execute.

Function in which I am calling createCookie(name)

```
function login() {
    var user = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var pass = document.getElementById('pass').value;
        if(user='Jacob',pass='password') {
        createCookie('name','Jacob',0);
        }else{
        alert('Invalid Credentials');
    }
}
```

The createCookie(name) Function

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
```

When I try to find the value using these functions it is displayed as null.

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function display(){
    var x = readCookie('name');
    alert(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, your code stores and retrieves the cookie just fine, but there is a large bug in your code:

```
if(user='Jacob',pass='password') {
```

This means "assign `'Jacob'` to `user`, assign `'password'` to `pass`, then produce the value `'password'`" (which will always be treated as `true`).

What you need is:

```
if(user === 'Jacob' && pass === 'password') {
```

Also, don't skimp on curly braces. There are plenty of them to go around and your code will be a mess without them. The following seems to work fine:

```
function login() {
    var user = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var pass = document.getElementById('pass').value;
    if (user === 'Jacob' && pass === 'password') {
        createCookie('name', 'Jacob', 0);
    } else {
        alert('Invalid Credentials');
    }
}

function createCookie(key, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        var expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = key + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(key) {
    var keyEq = key + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
            return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function display() {
    var x = readCookie('name');
    alert(x);
}
```

Also note that `readCookie` can be replaced with:

```
function readCookie(key) {
    return document.cookie.split(';').map(function (item) {
        return item.split('=').map(decodeURIComponent);
    }).filter(function (item) {
        return item[0] && item[0].trim() === key;
    }).map(function (item) {
        return item[1];
    })[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working-

```
var createCookie = function(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();

    }
    else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) {
                c_end = document.cookie.length;
            }
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
createCookie('username','Jacob',0);
alert(getCookie('username'));
```

Fiddle Url-https://jsfiddle.net/zr6h8nf7/3/

Comment: This was not the reason

Comment: @Jacob, the above code is working, I tested this in fiddle and provided the link, please check if this works for you as well

Comment: This isn't quit what I am looking for. I want create the cookie when a button is pressed and the condition is true. Although the condition is true in the code, the creatCooke function is ignored.